# Does the controllerAs pattern improve performance in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm being told that the controllerAs pattern improves AngularJS apps performance, by attaching less things on the scope.

I cannot really understand how this happens, since with controllerAs the controller itself exposes it's properties on the scope.

Does this really improve performance ? 
And if yes, then how and why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ControllerAs Syntax doesn't in itself increase an app's performance, but it does encourage other programming patterns which have a major impact on performance.

Most notably, the use of `$scope` as a repository for variables has the effect of encouraging using `$scope` globally, whereby programmers get used to things being added to the scope being accessible from anywhere.  This is a major pitfall that can create many performance issues.

Also when using ControllerAs, because the controller instance will be the only property on `$scope`, all of the fields on the view template will be a reference attribute. this can avoid the [JavaScript prototype](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance) chain inheritance pit.

The [Angular Best Practice](http://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-best-coding-practice-every-coder-should-follow/) Always have a `.` in binding expressions is automatically, naturally enforced by the ControllerAs syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the motivation for using the "controller" for binding to the view has to do with following best practices for MVC rather than having to do with performance.

```
Model - JSON objects
View - Directives
Controller - ngControllers
```

The job of the controller is to **mediate the interaction between services and the view's model** (in AngularJS the view model is represented by scope).

The job of the view model is to represent the model for the view, so it should not contain any significant logic.

The best place then for controller logic is in the controller itself - event handlers should be calling  controller methods, which calls a service returning a model, that is then saved on the views scope.
The view (directives) consume the model (scope), to render the final view.

Personally, I would like to see a change in the angular framework to have controllerAs way of calling methods implicit in the view and do away with binding methods on scope. With regards to this specific topic, I haven't found calling functions in a closure from the view very useful.